# Eject USB-Disk via Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I tried this code to eject the usb-device:

```
$drive = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application
$drive.NameSpace(17).Parsename("E:").InvokeVerb("Eject")
```

It worked on USB-Sticks. However, on USB-Disk it did not.

I tried the following either. It supposed to eject the drive but it just removed the drive letter :

Does someone know a way to eject a usb-Disk using a powershell skript ?

Comment: Please **DO NOT** add code as a linked image. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55951564/edit) your question and copy/paste the code as formatted text. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189) is how to do that.

Comment: I tried it but somehow i could not click on post. It has said the code is not good formulated. That is why i linked an image.

Comment: Don't mix up German with English ... Otherwise you'll reduce the amount of people that might help you.